# Anyway to stop 2008 and 2012 Visual Studio builds mixing through TeamCity?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, teamcity

I have a legacy system, with C++ dlls, libs, and exes. 
We build against either 2008 or 2012.

Obviously if a 2008 dll gets accidentally added to a 2012 build via TeamCity. That will be bad. Crashy. And vice versa.

So does anyone know of a way to get TeamCity to stop that being able to happen. I feel it must be possible as TeamCity runs the builds and as such 'knows' how each artifact was created. Surely there is some way to create a rule or such like that says 'Only 2008 artifacts for this build, otherwise error'?

Can I setup TeamCity to stop accidental 2008 and 2012 build mixes happening? (without using magic).

Ta!

Example:

My2008TeamCity build (Product built using 2008)
Requires artifacts a2008, b2008, c2008

My2012TeamCity build (Product built using 2012)
Requires artifacts a2012, b2012, c2012

The artifacts are DLL's and loaded at run time only.

Recently we ran the My2008TeamCity build.
A few of the artifacts had mistakenly been setup, through TeamCity to come from 2012 builds.
i.e. a2012 was added to a 2008 build as an artifact.

As the DLL is only loaded run at runtime, we didn't notice the problem until the code was manually run, and that part of the code hit.

Now imagine a huge system, with loads of artifacts, many developers working on subprojects constantly... and something that can guard against this happening suddenly feels required.

Ideally I would like TeamCity to say 'No this artifact was build against 2012, and you are running a 2008 build' and fail the build. So we can fix it.
X

Answer (score 0):

I not clearly sure, are you using all of this in one solution? You can use separate folders of VCS(Build Configuration Settings\Version Control Settings\Edit checkout rules) and for configuration "2012" take only this folder from VCS.

Comment: Good idea but I don't think that solves my problem. On TeamCity I have one build which pulls together lots of artifacts. I want something to ensure that all dll artifacts have been build using the same VS version, and thus they target the same C++ re-distributable.

Comment: Hm.. What about to make 2 project in solution, 2008 and 2012, and include another projects into it. Next, in TC instead of building solution try to make 2 build steps for build 2008 and 2012 projects? 
Or ,maybe , you can show example of problem?

Comment: I've added an example. Hope that clarifies my question further. (and why your excellent suggestion will not work).